# Is there a relativistic quantum open string that does not proceed from Fourier mode expansions?

Tags: string-theory, fourier-transform

I am afraid of what I am going to be typing next. I have now read and thought a little about chapter 9 and chapter 12 of Ziebach's string theory text "A First Course in String Theory" 2nd edition. It seems to me that the key idea that makes the relativistic open string pop is that of Fourier series expansions (classical Virasoro modes)  and the realization that transverse Virasoro modes will be important.

When these ideas are lifted to the quantum case the transverse Virasoro operators are found.

The Hamiltonian is

$$H = L_0 ^\perp - 1.$$

I am still thinking through this and have done only quick reading of chapter 12 so far, but it seems that the "open string theory" business is *literally* the quantum mechanics of the relativistic open strings.

**Question**

*What would have been if we did not do the Fourier series expansion? Is there a story that proceeds outside of the Virasoro modes?*

Comment: [Path integral quantization of the Polyakov action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosonic_string_theory#Path_integral_perturbation_theory)

Comment: @Ghoster The part about this article that brought up the conformal anomaly was interesting and raised some questions. To check  Weyl invariance, one would replace the old metric with another one (the new metric defined in terms of the old one) in place of the old one into the action $S$ and hope the action will remain unchanged.  This seems to work. for the new action. New action is old action $S'$ = $S$. It seems the anomaly part comes from demanding that the whole path integral thing $\mathcal{Z}$ obey that symmetry.

Comment: @Ghoster It then seems that one goes back and modifies $S$ by adding some counterterm so that $\mathcal{Z}$ works out to be Weyl invariant too.

Comment: @Ghoster I am going to try some calculational experiments today at some point but this is what I think is going on from doing some reading and thinking. I don't know but it seems 26 dimensions is important somehow too in this story.

Comment: Section 2.4 of [these notes](https://inis.iaea.org/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/40/084/40084717.pdf) has more detail on path integral quantization of the bosonic string, including where the 26 emerges in this approach.